# Speed up Python/Numpy Code for Ising-/Potts-Model Monte-Carlo

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, montecarlo

For a small side-project I have written an 2D Ising-/Potts-Model Monte-Carlo simulation in Python/Numpy with the (simplified) code below.

Essentially the code does the following:

- Sets up a NXM array filled with random integers (*orientations*) in [1,orientations]
- for every time-step (*MCS*) the every pixel of the array is visited once in a pseudo-randomized order (therefore largest prime under() and
  `index = (a*i + rand) % (N**2)
      x = index % N
      y = index // N`  )
- the 8 neighboring array entries are checked (periodic boundary conditions) and the entry is changed to one of the neighboring values
- if the energy of the new configuration becomes lower the change is accepted, else it is rejected unless a condition is fulfilled

I tried to speed it up as much as I could think of, but for large arrays (N,M > 500) the code isn't really fast. As I need about 10e5 MCS for an array to see a clear trend, the achieved

```
1 loop, best of 3: 276 ms per loop
```

for 1 MCS on a 100x100 array isn't really sufficient. Unfortunately I don't know how to increase the performance given my lack of experience.

I assume the Neighbors() and the calc_dE() functions are the bottle-necks and especially the nested loops but I can't find a way to speed it up. My cython trys weren't really successful as I haven't done anything with cython before so I'm open to any suggestion.

CODE:

(The pyplot commands are just for visualization and are usually commented.)

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def largest_primes_under(N):
    n = N - 1
    while n >= 2:
        if all(n % d for d in range(2, int(n ** 0.5 + 1))):
            return n
        n -= 1

def Neighbors(Lattice,i,j,n=1):
    ''' Returns an flat array of all neighboring sites in the n-th coordination sphere including the center'''
    N, M = Lattice.shape
    rows = [(i-1) % N, i, (i+1) % N]
    cols = [(j-1) % N, j, (j+1) % M]
    return Lattice[rows][:, cols].flatten()

def calc_dE(Lattice, x, y, z):
    N, M = Lattice.shape
    old_energy = 0
    new_energy = 0
    for i in [0,1,-1]:
        for j in [0,1,-1]:
            if i == 0 and j == 0: 
                continue
            if Lattice[x%N,y%M] == Lattice[(x+i)%N,(y+j)%M]:
                old_energy += 1
            elif z == Lattice[(x+i)%N,(y+j)%M]: 
                new_energy += 1 
    return old_energy-new_energy

N, M = 100,100
orientations = N*M
MCS = int(100)

a = largest_primes_under(N*M)
L = np.random.randint(1,orientations+1,size=(N,M))

mat = plt.matshow(L,cmap = plt.get_cmap('plasma', orientations+1), vmin = -0.5, vmax = orientations+0.5, interpolation='kaiser')
plt.axis('off')

for t in range(1,MCS+1):
    rand = np.random.random_integers(N*M)
    for i in range(0,N**2):
        index = (a*i + rand) % (N**2)
        x = index % N
        y = index // N
        n = Neighbors(L,x,y)
        if len(n)-1 == 0: 
            continue
        else: 
            z = np.random.choice(n)
        dE = calc_dE(L,x,y,z)
        if  (dE < 0): 
            L[x%N,y%N] = z      
        elif np.random.sample() < math.exp(-dE*2.5): 
            L[x%N,y%N] = z

    mat.set_data(L)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.0001)
```

Comment: This needs to be posted on Code Review but `if len(n)-1 == 0: continue` in a single line, with an `else` after, is unintelligible at first glance to me. Use PEP8. There is no brownie badge for having everything on one line.

Comment: @roganjosh Done as well as I could by an edit – sorry…no programmer but chemist. Sometimes these things just slip my mind. So you think I should cross-post to Code Review?

Comment: No, don't cross-post. I'm a Chemical Engineer by teaching but PEP8 really does get ingrained in how you read code. Thanks for your changes, I'm out atm but it will be easier to follow for others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you have any sort of restrictions in terms of dependencies, but I would definitely look into [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/). It provides a set of decorators (`njit`, in particular) that will compile your code to machine code and make it potentially much, much faster, provided you are using compatible types (e.g. numpy arrays, but not pandas DataFrames).

Also, not sure what scale you are looking at, but I'm quite you can find examples of much better optimized prime search algorithms than a manually implemented for loop.

Otherwise you can always fall-back on Cython, but it requires re-writing your code.

---

**EDIT**: ok, I gave it a try with numba.

A few notes:

1. moved the whole for loop inside a function, so that you can decorate it with `njit`
2. in `Neighbors`, I had to change `rows` and `cols` from `list`s to `np.array`s because numba does not accept indexing through lists
3. I replaced `np.random.random_integers` with `np.random.randint` since the former is deprecated
4. I replaced `math.exp` with `np.exp` which should give a minor performance boost (besides saving you an import)

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

def largest_primes_under(N):
    n = N - 1
    while n >= 2:
        if all(n % d for d in range(2, int(n ** 0.5 + 1))):
            return n
        n -= 1

@njit
def Neighbors(Lattice,i,j,n=1):
    ''' Returns an flat array of all neighboring sites in the n-th coordination sphere including the center'''
    N, M = Lattice.shape
    rows = np.array([(i-1) % N, i, (i+1) % N])
    cols = np.array([(j-1) % N, j, (j+1) % M])
    return Lattice[rows,:][:,cols].flatten()

@njit
def calc_dE(Lattice, x, y, z):
    N, M = Lattice.shape
    old_energy = 0
    new_energy = 0
    for i in [0,1,-1]:
        for j in [0,1,-1]:
            if i == 0 and j == 0: 
                continue
            if Lattice[x%N,y%M] == Lattice[(x+i)%N,(y+j)%M]:
                old_energy += 1
            elif z == Lattice[(x+i)%N,(y+j)%M]: 
                new_energy += 1 
    return old_energy-new_energy

@njit
def fun(L, MCS, a):
    N, M = L.shape

    for t in range(1,MCS+1):
        rand = np.random.randint(N*M)
        for i in range(0,N**2):
            index = (a*i + rand) % (N**2)
            x = index % N
            y = index // N
            n = Neighbors(L,x,y)
            if len(n)-1 == 0: continue
            else: z = np.random.choice(n)
            dE = calc_dE(L,x,y,z)
            if  (dE < 0): L[x%N,y%N] = z      
            elif np.random.sample() < np.exp(-dE*2.5): L[x%N,y%N] = z    
    return L
```

Running the same example

```py
N, M = 100,100
orientations = N*M
MCS = 1

L = np.random.randint(1,orientations+1,size=(N,M))
a = largest_primes_under(N*M)
```

through `%timeit fun(L, MCS, a)` (in Jupyter) gives me

```py
16.9 ms ± 853 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

which is ~15 times faster than what you currently have. There are probably more optimizations you can do, the nice thing about numba is that I obtained a x15 speed up without delving into or changing significantly how your code is implemented.

A couple of general observations:

1. in `Neighbors`, the argument/parameter `n` is not used, so you should remove it for clarity (or update the code)
2. in Python, you generally want to use lowercase for function names and variables. Uppercase it usually reserved for Classes (not objects) and "global" variables
3. Your comment above about `largest_primes_under` being called only once is definitely spot on, I should have looked better at the code.

> premature optimization is the root of all evil

Comment: I know the prime finding is crude, but this is only done once outside the loop so it shouldn't really slow down the code right? I'll have a look at Numba!

Comment: Nicely done. I wasn't aware of the pssibilities Numba offers. That's an excellent starting-point. As for your observations : 1.) 'n' in 'Neighbors' was used for a second coordination sphere, which I removed for testing and debugging. 2.) right. I should maybe have another look at PEP8! 3.) No worries…I'm not really sure, if that's the best way for the pseudo-randomization of the array indexes and I gave it a quick and dirty try – maybe I should think of something else.

Comment: I did upvote but I don't have enough reputation to show the vote. I'll wait another day – maybe someone has additional ideas to gain some ms. If not I'll gladly accept your answer.

Comment: definitely wait for more suggestions! I haven't really looked at the implementation, I'm sure there are others improvements you can make

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the code, which I found very useful for supporting a course on Monte Carlo that I'm developing (and also to Giorgio for the optimizations). However, I believe there may be a critical flaw in your original code above, which leads to problems in simulating above or around the critical point.
I believe that the line

```
z = np.random.choice(n)
```

should be

```
z = np.random.choice(orientations)+1
```

otherwise the code will not be able to escape from a configuration where all neighbouring spins have the same orientation. This is particularly important when looking at the limiting case of Ising model (orientations = 2) above the critical point (kT/J = 2.27, which in your code would mean changing the beta factor from 2.5 to 0.441).
Hope this is helpful.